# Bash scripting: List of folders in a variable and grep the exact directory name

Tags: bash, directory, grep

Here is my problem. To get a list of directory where the file GC.xml is:

> `EXBRANDS=`find /var/www/html/ -maxdepth 3 -name "GC.xml" -type f | awk -F '/' '{print $5}'`;`

`#echo $EXBRANDS`

`#dir1 dir2 dir3 (it appears exactly like this)`

`#read var`

Enter "dir" for example

That's where I'm having trouble to identify the exact pattern I typed to compare it against my directory list.

`echo $EXBRANDS | grep "[ $var]\|[$var ]\|[ $var]"
            if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then .....  else ..... fi;`

I think there is a problem with my grep command as if I pass the value "dir" to $var my grep command actually finds the directory and returns $?=0

My wish is to get $?=0 only if it finds exactly the pattern $var in my grep command...

What are the best grep (egrep) options here? Or is my method completely stupid?

Answer (score 2):

Your `EXBRANDS` contains many lines, and you loose these lines with echo.

I would do that the other way:

```
read var
find /var/www/html/ -maxdepth 3 -name "GC.xml" -type f | awk -F '/' '{print $5}' | grep "^$var\$"
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then ...  else ... fi;
```

Be sure that the grep match an exact line with the `"^$var\$"` construct.

**Edit**: you could also `printf "$EXBRANDS" | grep "^$var\$"` instead of echo, it might solve your problem.

Comment: this works but only if you dont need EXBRANDS in that format; using *EXBRANDS=&lsquo;find ...&lsquo;* put everything on the same line: "dir1 dir2 dir3"

Comment: Are you sure it is on the same line ?  If you do `echo $EXBRANDS`, it will appear on the same line because shell substitution occurs before parameter parsing, and as the parameters' delimiters are spaces, TABS, and new lines, you get everything on a single line.  Try `echo "$EXBRANDS"` which will send a single parameter to `echo` or `cat << EOF <new line> $EXBRANDS <new line> EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using word boundaries:

```
if [ ! -z "$var" ] ;  
    then echo $EXBRANDS | grep -e "\b$var\b"; 
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; 
        then echo "Y"; 
        else echo "N"; 
    fi;
    else echo "input dir must be not null"; 
fi;
```

**EDIT**: add null check

Comment: Ok that solved the issue but if I hit Enter for $var, it's seems to consider that $?=0... How can I get rid of this case as well?

Comment: just add some validation on $var before continuing execution, as i see no point on running the following code on empty strings. ie, test with *if [ -z "$var" ]* and exit gracefully with an error if true